# Calculate time difference (difftime) between columns of different rows

Tags: r, datetime, posixct, difftime

I have data on 'Start' and 'End' time for different jobs, grouped by 'owner':

```
Data <- data.frame(
  job = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  owner = c("name1", "name2", "name1", "name1", "name2"),
  Start = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 15:00:00", "2015-01-01 15:01:00", "2015-01-01 15:13:00", "2015-01-01 15:20:00", "2015-01-01 15:39:02"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
  End =   as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 15:11:11", "2015-01-01 15:17:21", "2015-01-01 15:17:00", "2015-01-01 15:31:21", "2015-01-01 15:40:11"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
)
```

For each owner, I want to calculate the idle time between the jobs for each owner, i.e. the difference between the 'End' time of one job and the 'Start' time of the next job.

How do I use `difftime()` to calculate this time difference between specific rows and times in different columns?

The result should look something like this:

```
job, owner, idletime
1, name1, NA
2, name2, NA
3, name1, 1.816667  # End of row 1 minus Start of row 3
4, name1, 3.0       # End of row 3 minus Start of row 4
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) # v 1.9.5+
setDT(Data)[, idletime := difftime(Start, shift(End), units = "mins"), by = owner]
#    job owner               Start                 End       idletime
# 1:   1 name1 2015-01-01 15:00:00 2015-01-01 15:11:11        NA mins
# 2:   2 name2 2015-01-01 15:01:00 2015-01-01 15:17:21        NA mins
# 3:   3 name1 2015-01-01 15:13:00 2015-01-01 15:17:00  1.816667 mins
# 4:   4 name1 2015-01-01 15:20:00 2015-01-01 15:31:21  3.000000 mins
# 5:   5 name2 2015-01-01 15:39:02 2015-01-01 15:40:11 21.683333 mins
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  group_by(owner) %>%
  mutate(idletime = difftime(Start, lag(End), units = "mins"))

# Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
# Groups: owner
# 
#   job owner               Start                 End       idletime
# 1   1 name1 2015-01-01 15:00:00 2015-01-01 15:11:11        NA mins
# 2   2 name2 2015-01-01 15:01:00 2015-01-01 15:17:21        NA mins
# 3   3 name1 2015-01-01 15:13:00 2015-01-01 15:17:00  1.816667 mins
# 4   4 name1 2015-01-01 15:20:00 2015-01-01 15:31:21  3.000000 mins
# 5   5 name2 2015-01-01 15:39:02 2015-01-01 15:40:11 21.683333 mins
```

Answer (score 3):

If we are using `base R`, `ave` would be one option.  We get the `lag` of the 'End' grouped by 'owner' using `ave`, use that as the second argument in `difftime` to create the 'idtime'.

```
Data$idtime <- with(Data, difftime(Start, ave(End, owner,FUN=lag), units='mins'))

Data
#  job owner               Start                 End         idtime
#1   1 name1 2015-01-01 15:00:00 2015-01-01 15:11:11        NA mins
#2   2 name2 2015-01-01 15:01:00 2015-01-01 15:17:21        NA mins
#3   3 name1 2015-01-01 15:13:00 2015-01-01 15:17:00  1.816667 mins
#4   4 name1 2015-01-01 15:20:00 2015-01-01 15:31:21  3.000000 mins
#5   5 name2 2015-01-01 15:39:02 2015-01-01 15:40:11 21.683333 mins
```

NOTE: I named the column name as 'idtime' to keep the code in a single line :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)


Data <- data.frame(
  job = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  owner = c("name1", "name2", "name1", "name1", "name2"),
  Start = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 15:00:00", "2015-01-01 15:01:00", "2015-01-01 15:13:00", "2015-01-01 15:20:00", "2015-01-01 15:39:02"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
  End =   as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 15:11:11", "2015-01-01 15:17:21", "2015-01-01 15:17:00", "2015-01-01 15:31:21", "2015-01-01 15:40:11"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
)


Data %>% 
  group_by(owner) %>% 
  arrange(Start) %>% 
  mutate(lagEnd = lag(End),
         idletime = difftime(Start,lagEnd, units="mins")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(job) %>%
  select(job,owner,idletime)

#   job owner        idletime
# 1   1 name1         NA mins
# 2   2 name2         NA mins
# 3   3 name1   1.816667 mins
# 4   4 name1   3.000000 mins
# 5   5 name2  21.683333 mins
```